# How can I make a quiz using random numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, random

```
name = input('What is your name?')
print('Welcome to my quiz',name)
guess = 0
tries = 0
answer = 5
score = 0
while guess != answer and tries < 2:
    guess = int(input("10/2 is..."))
    if guess == answer:
       print ("Correct")
       score = score + 1
    else:
       print ("Incorrect")
       score = score + 0
    tries = tries + 1
guess = 0
tries = 0
answer = 25
while guess != answer and tries <2:
    guess = int(input("5*5 is..."))
    if guess == answer:
      print("Correct")
      score = score + 1
    else:
      print("Incorrect")
      score = score + 0
    tries = tries + 1
print("Thank you for playing",name,". You scored",score,"points")
```

I'm trying to loop the questions with random numbers but I'm not sure how to do it. How can I make a quiz that asks the user multiplication, addition, subtraction and division questions using random numbers and records their scores.

Comment: You have an indentation error in your pasted code.

Comment: Please tag it as python-3 if it is a Python v3.0 question

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(0,10)
3
>>> random.randint(0,10)
8
>>> random.randint(0,10)
10
```

You can use python [**random**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) library to generate random number for your question.

```
>>> help(random.randint)
Help on method randint in module random:

randint(a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
```

So you can give a range to **random.randint** method and it will generate unique values for you each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the module random. The coding would look something like this.

```
import random
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('Welcome to my quiz',name)
guess = 0
tries = 0
answer = 1
score = 0

num1=random.randint(1,100) #you can use whatever numbers you want here
num2=random.randint(1,100) #see above
answer=num1+num2
while guess != answer and tries < 2:
    #print("What is",num1,"+",num2,"?") #you can use print or...
    question="What is the sum of " + str(num1) +"+"+ str(num2)+"? "
    guess=float(input(question)) #if you use print, remove the word question
    if guess == answer:
       print ("Correct")
       score = score + 1
    else:
       print ("Incorrect")
       score = score + 0
    tries+=1
guess=0
tries = 0
num1=random.randint(1,100) #you can use whatever numbers you want here
num2=random.randint(1,100) #see above
answer=num1*num2
while guess != answer and tries <2:

    #print("What is",num1,"*",num2,"?") #you can use print or...
    question="What is the product of " + str(num1) +"*"+ str(num2)+"? "
    guess=float(input(question)) #if you use print, remove the word question
    if guess == answer:
      print("Correct")
      score = score + 1
    else:
      print("Incorrect")
      score = score + 0
    tries+=1
print("Thank you for playing",name,". You scored",score,"points")
```

What I did was I created two random numbers(num1 and num2), and then added/multiplied them together. Hope this helps answer your question.